# Popup removes scroll bar, trying to make it appear again

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

[This website](https://www.healthline.com/health/does-cold-weather-make-you-sick) asks to accept privacy terms before I can read it's content, but the content is already loaded, however there is no scroll bar, and I'm trying to make it appear.

I managed to remove the "please accept..." prompt.

I tried setting `overflow: visible` in the body, but it didn't help.
I also tried `overwlow-y: scroll` and it made the scroll bar appear, but the scroller itself was missing.

How can I put a functioning scroll bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I had to put `overflow: visible` on the body, and delete:
`<style data-emotion></style> == $0`

[The things I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zEya.png)